# Input Signal Out of Range

Tags: arch-linux, display, plasma5

I've installed Arch Linux and Plasma Desktop on one of my old PCs (12yrs or more), it's AMD Phenom II Quad Core, ATI Radeon 3000 and 4 GB RAM. On Samsung SyncMaster S19B150 (max res 1366x768) it works but fonts are choppy so I wanted to test it on a lenovo ThinkVision L1900p 19-inch Monitor BUT it displays a messege `input signal out of range`! lenovo actually works fine on another old (15 yrs or more) Windows machine with Intel Dual Core.

How can I get rid of that error on lenovo and make plasma desktop work on that monitor?

---

EDIT

I'm not sure whether it's an Arch specific problem. If I plug in live ubuntu usb-stick or live KDE neon usb-stick, it works, fonts everywhere seems alright BUT the screen resolution is low!

[image]
[image]

I've no problem with this monitor on windows with 1280x1024.

---

Edit

It must be an Arch specific problem or I don't know how to resolve this issue on Arch yet! Void linux with Plasma desktop works fine on this monitor except for that low 1024x768 resolution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution for this problem is change the VGA connector. I don't know why did it come into my mind after so long: I just took off the VGA connector of SyncMaster and plugged that in to lenovo! Now I can see "Arch with plasma desktop" on its optimum resolution 1280x1024 and on this monitor I don't have the choppy font issue.

[image]